# Properly way for obtaining the N latest videos of channel : search vs playlistItem vs activities endpoints

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm developing for a web app that needs to retrieve the last 10 videos of a user(channel).

### First approach

Was to use the search endpoint with param 'forMine' ordering by date, but then I figured that maybe that param could retrieve videos uploaded by the user in a diferent channel or whatever...

[First result with channel ID and date - 1st Aproach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b5kh.png)

### Second approach

Was to use the search endpoint with param 'channelId' ordering by date, but then I realized that descriptions were incomplete and most importantly there were some videos missing comparing with first aproach, even if the missing videos belonged to same channel (as showed in pics links)

[First resutl with channel ID and date - 2nd Aproach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqXQP.png)

So, then I googled to find some solution and found other way.

### Third approach

Was to use the playlistItem endpoint as I found in Google, and seemed ok (I supposed) because it returned same videos that first aproach and consumed less quota but this method  left me with doubts as I didn't knew if the videos would be the latest or maybe they would be sorted by position in the playlist and couldn't be trusted to be the most recent

That said, what would be the correct way to get the N most recent videos from a channel, please?
Regardless of the quota consumption (the less quota the better, of course, but an accurate result is essential)

I'm so confussed with the API response...

Thank you so much!

---

-- EDITED: NEW APPROACH AND FURTHER INVESTIGATIONS --

### Fourth approach

Was to use activities endpoint as was stated by @stvar in his answer. I found that this way, as on second approach, there were some videos missing comparing with first and third approaches, and it was required to retrieve everything without 'maxResults' param because there were activities not related to video upload, making mandatory to perform pagination and a self filtering by type 'upload' after retrieving response in order to get N videos (or be confident in getting N videos uploaded in first 50 retrieved items)

### Self Investigations

Further investigations and tests bringed me response to the issue of 'missing videos' of some approaches.
The status of that missing videos were 'unlisted', so they were videos uploaded to the channel, property of the channel, uploaded by user of the channel... but not retrieved by some methods that seemed to retrieve only 'public' videos not 'unlisted' (hidden) nor 'private'.

***NOTE**: I did my test with Google API PHP Client Library, this behaviour seems not to be on 'Try this API' as it returns only 'public' items, so be careful on trust in 'Try this API' results as it seems to use some hidden filters or something...*

Also I tested the channel upload playlist to verify that the order can not be changed and has a LIFO sorting

---

### CONCLUSIONS

At this point, my self conclusion is that there is not a proper way to solve this but quite ways to do it in depend of requisites of status and amount of free quota

**Search endpoint** seems to work all right, if you have a good amount of unused quota (100 each call) that is the direct way and easiest one as you can sort it and filtering as needed by a bunch of params, taking care to use 'forMine' param if you need every uploaded video or 'channelId' if you need only 'listed' and 'public' ones.

**PlaylistItems endpoint** is a proper way if you are in a quota crisis (1 each call) as the result is sorted by recent date, taking care to do pagination and post filtering if only 'public' videos are needed till retrieve the desired amount of video ids, otherwhise you can go all the way easy.

> Note that the date used to order is the upload date not the post date
> (thanks to @stvar for bringing this to the attention)

**Activity endpoint**, also for quota crisis (1 each call), while it could be more accurate than the others if you only want public videos (it is ordered by recent 'first publish date' so not accurate 100% neither ), is for me the one that gives more work, as it retrieves activities other than 'video upload', so you can not skip pagination and post filtering to retrieve the desired amount of video ids, besides that way you only have access, as said before, to public videos (which is fine if that meets your needs).

Anyway, if you need more than 50 ids, you need to make pagination whatever the aproach you use.

Hope this help someone else and thanks so much to contributors

PS: People in charge of the YouTube API, perhaps a filter by state among some others would be interesting, Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63565437/edit) your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help). Important thing: please obey to SO guidelines: [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8327971), but ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) plain text.

Comment: For what concerns your PS, I suggest you better file a feature request to Google's own [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/). Then wait and see the staff's response.

Comment: Thanks @stvar again for comments, I read before deletion and take them in count for update conclusions

Comment: Sorry, @Sergio, if causing you confusion! The last couple of hours I was searching back (locally on my computer and here on SO within my answers) proof for my claim that *`PlaylistItems.list` produces items ordered by upload date*. Unfortunately, I didn't find such a proof. Also I tested the endpoint, and it seems that it produces items sorted by [`videoPublishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.videoPublishedAt) (you may check that yourself).

Comment: Therefore, please excuse my mistake: I do have to retract my claim. It may have been valid in the past, but, right now, is not. This may well be interpreted as a classic example: one is relying on undocumented behavior of an API -- then, the API's implementation changes without notice (while the API itself does not), breaking off client application assumptions that were true in the past.

Comment: Here is an example of a channel -- `UCAvx9uxtvhnxNpnjutUei5A` -- that exhibits the behavior I described above: has its uploads playlist items sorted by `contentDetails.videoPublishedAt`, but not by `snippet.publishedAt`. (The culprit: the 4th item, `hCk00BUbMBU`).

Comment: No, you help me a lot @stvar, nothing of confusion. I tested what you said of both activities and playlistItems, and update conclusions with the API behaviour. PlaylistItems list sorts by upload date as you said Activities list sorts by published date, but only the 'first published date'. So if a video is published by error, and then setted to hidden or private or whatever... the next time it comes published it take the first date, wich is not accurate neither

Answer (score 1):

You may employ the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint, queried with:

- `mine=true`,
- `part=snippet,contentDetails`,
- `fields=items(snippet(type),contentDetails(upload))`, and
- `maxResults=50`.

For to obtain your desired `N` uploads, you have to implement [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination). That is that you have to successively call the endpoint until you reach `N` result set items that have `snippet.type` equal with `upload`.

Note that you may well use `channelId=CHANNEL_ID` instead of `mine=true`, if you're interested about the most recent uploads of a channel identified by its ID `CHANNEL_ID` rather than your own channel.

According to the docs, you'll get from this endpoint a result set made of [`Activities resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource) items that will contain the following info:

> [**contentDetails.upload**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.upload) (object)
> The upload object contains information about the uploaded video. This property is only present if the `snippet.type` is `upload`.
>
> [**contentDetails.upload.videoId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.upload.videoId) (string)
> The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the uploaded video.

The official docs state that each call to `Activities.list` endpoint has a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one unit.

---

Futhermore, upon obtaining a set of video IDs, you may invoke the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with a properly assigned [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) parameter, for to obtain from the endpoint all the details you need for each and every video of your interest.

Note that if you have a set of video IDs of cardinality `K`, since the parameter `id` of `Videos.list` endpoint can be specified as a comma-separated list of video IDs, then you may reduce the number of calls to `Videos.list` endpoint from `K` to `floor(K / 50) + (K % 50 ? 1 : 0)` by appropriately using the feature of `id` just mentioned.

According to the official docs, each call to `Videos.list` endpoint has also a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one unit.

---

**Clarifications upon OP's request**:

*Question no. 1*: The `Activities.list` endpoint produces only the activities specified by the [Activities resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource). The `type` property enumerates them all:

> [**snippet.type**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.type) (string)
> The type of activity that the resource describes.
>
> Valid values for this property are: *channelItem*, *comment* (not currently returned), *favorite*, *like*, *playlistItem*, *promotedItem*, *recommendation*, *social*, *subscription*, *upload*, *bulletin* (deprecated).

Indeed your remark is correct. For example, when getting the most recent `10` uploads, is possible that you'll have to scan a number of pages `P` of result sets, with `P >= 2`, until you reached collecting the desired `10` upload items. (Actual tests have confirmed me this to be factual.)

*Question no. 2*: The `Activities.list` endpoint produces items that are sorted by [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.publishedAt); just replace the above `fields` with:

`fields=items(snippet(type,publishedAt),contentDetails(upload))`

and see that for yourself.

I could make here the following argument *justifying the necessity* that the items resulted upon the invocation of `Activities.list` endpoint be ordered chronologically by `publishedAt` (the newest first). One may note that, indeed, the official docs quoted above do not specify explicitly that ordering condition I just mentioned; but bare with me for a while:

My argument is of a pragmatic kind: if the result set of `Activities.list` is not ordered as mentioned, then this endpoint *becomes useless*. This is so, since, in this case, for one to obtain the most recent upload activity *would have to fetch locally all* the upload activities, for to then scan that result set for the most recent one. Being compelled to fetch all upload activities only for to obtain the newest one is pragmatically a nonsense. Therefore, by way of contradiction, the result set *has to be ordered* chronologically by `publishedAt` with the newest being the first.

*Question no. 3*: Indeed [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) is not precise -- it has a fuzzy behavior. I can confirm this based on my own experience; but, unfortunately, I cannot point you to official docs (from Google or YouTube) that acknowledge and explain this behavior. As unfortunate as it is, for its users `Search.list` is completely opaque.

On the other hand, `Activities.list` is precise -- it has to be like that; if it wouldn't be precise, then that's a serious bug in the implementation (in my educated opinion).

Comment: Thanks for your help... it generates some doubts:
1. Could this approach recover any activity other than video upload? That would mean not being able to limit the results and go through all of them until I get the number of results for the activity I want.
2. Are they always sorted by most recent date?
3. I am missing videos as was the case with the second approach, why could this happen?

Thanks

Comment: I read it and I did some test and researches... 
I updated my question and gave myself conclusion